# Windows 10 BSOD restarting : APC Index Mismatch

Tags: windows-10

I have purchased a new HP Laptop. After various Windows 10 updates, it began rebooting at startup several times with BSOD error: APC Index Mismatch.

Currently running SUPERAntiSpyware, CCleaner, & Malwarebytes.

Comment: New? Return it while still on warranty.

Comment: Can you make available a dump of the bugcheck?  Is there a file or files under: C:\windows\minidump\ that correspond the BSODs?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/hardware/ff557419(v=vs.85).aspx